# How can I create a polygon on an Argand diagram

Tags: diagrams

[image]

How am I able to make a diagram like this where the points are connected to form a polygon (so a pentagon in this case) with the axis being in the middle.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question precisely: how do you draw the pentagon?

With Tikz : you need to know the vertices (A,B,C,D,E) :

```
 \draw (A) \foreach \pt in {A,B,C,D,E}{--(\pt)}--cycle;%
```

With tkz-euclide : `\tkzDrawPolygon(A,...,E)`

With the new tkz-elements package (you need to compile with `lualatex`). If you want 4,6 or 7 sides, you need only to change
 `RP.five  = regular_polygon : new (z.O,z.A,5)` you remove 5 and add what you want. `A` is the first vertex.

`RP.five : name ("A_")` is a function to get good names for the nodes. With lua the first indice is 1 but we can modify that.

You can get the exradius and the inradius effortless
In your latex code : `\tkzUseLua{RP.five.inradius}` here :4.8541019662497

You can get the length of a side  : `\tkzUseLua{RP.five.side}` : 3.5267115137548

Remark : I didn't put much effort into label placement. You need to use the TikZ styles to improve placement.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[margin=6pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\begin{document} 
    
\begin{tkzelements}
   z.A      = point : new ( 0  , -6  )
   z.O      = point : new ( 0  , 0  )
   RP.five  = regular_polygon : new (z.O,z.A,5)
   RP.five : name ("A_")
   z.H = RP.five.proj
\end{tkzelements}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \tkzGetNodes
   \tkzInit[xmin=-7,ymax=7,xmax=7,ymin=-7]
   \tkzDrawX[>=latex,label = Re($z$)]
   \tkzDrawY[>=latex,label = Im($z$)]
   \tkzGrid
   \tkzDrawCircles[red](O,A)
   \tkzDrawCircles[teal](O,H)
   \tkzDrawPolygon(A_1,A_...,A_5)
   \tkzDrawPoints[red](A_1,A_...,A_5)
   \tkzLabelPoints[red](A_1,A_...,A_5)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]
Code in `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!20,step=.5] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {Re$z$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {Im$z$};
        \draw (1,.05)--(1,-.05) node[below] () {\tiny 1};
        \draw (.05,1)--(-.05,1) node[left] () {\tiny 1};
        \draw[color=magenta,dotted] (0,0) circle(3cm);
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} 
        \filldraw[red] ({54+72*\i}:3) circle(1.5pt) coordinate (a\i);
        \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a0)--(a1) coordinate[pos=.25] (c0) {};
        \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a1)--(a2) coordinate[pos=.25] (c1) {};
        \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a2)--(a3) coordinate[pos=.25] (c2) {};
        \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a3)--(a4) coordinate[pos=.25] (c3) {};
        \draw[blue,line width=1pt] (a4)--(a0) coordinate[pos=.25] (c4) {};
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} \draw[black] ({54+72*\i}:3.3) node (b\i) {$A_{\i}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ADD:**
I dont like supplementary packets when not strictly necessary. So I propose also another minimalist solution (same output):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[gray!20,step=.5] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
        \draw[-latex] (-4,0)--(4,0) node[right] {Re$z$};
        \draw[-latex] (0,-4)--(0,4) node[above] {Im$z$};
        \draw (1,.05)--(1,-.05) node[below] () {\tiny 1};
        \draw (.05,1)--(-.05,1) node[left] () {\tiny 1};
        \draw[color=magenta,dotted] (0,0) circle(3cm);
        \draw[line width=1pt] (54:3) node[red] {} circle(1pt)--(126:3) node[red] {} circle(1pt)--(198:3) node[red] {} circle(1pt)--(270:3) node[red] {} circle(1pt)--(342:3) node[red] {} circle(1pt)--(54:3);
        \foreach \i in {0,1,2,3,4} \draw[black] ({54+72*\i}:3.3) node (b\i) {$A_{\i}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```